# How to fix "AOP configuration seems to be invalid" error?

Tags: spring, aop, bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am developing a plugin for Bitbucket using atlassian-sdk. When I try to use GitCommandFactory, I run into the below error:

```
"AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method [public 
abstract com.atlassian.bitbucket.scm.git.command.GitCommandFactory 
com.atlassian.bitbucket.scm.git.GitScm.getCommandFactory()] on target 
[com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.DefaultGitScm@321c944]; nested 
exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an 
instance of declaring class"
```

This is the line of code that throws the error:

```
 GitCommandFactory gitCommandFactory = gitScm.getCommandFactory();
```

A glimpse of my class and the constructor:

```
 @ComponentImport
private final PullRequestService pullRequestService;
@ComponentImport
private final GitScm gitScm;
@ComponentImport
private final GitScmConfig gitScmConfig;
@ComponentImport
private final EventPublisher eventPublisher;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


private Logger loggerLocal;

@Autowired
public SquashServlet(PullRequestService pullRequestService, GitScm gitScm, GitScmConfig gitScmConfig, EventPublisher eventPublisher) throws Exception{
    super();
    this.pullRequestService = pullRequestService;
    this.gitScm = gitScm;
    this.gitScmConfig = gitScmConfig;
    this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;

    FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("BitBuckSquash.log",true);
    this.loggerLocal = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.atlassian.kaushik.plugin.servlet");
    loggerLocal.addHandler(handler);
}
```

How do I solve this issue? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue. It was due to incompatible dependencies.

I had to add the version number that is equal to my bitbucket's version in the pom.xml and it worked.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.bitbucket.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>bitbucket-git-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>${bitbucket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```